# Queries regarding the use and behaviour of the JavaFX Pagination control

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, pagination

I've been creating some GUIs that have several panes and the user needs to be able to switch between these. I've therefore been looking at the built-in controls that will allow me to handle this. Two obvious choices I believe are the TabPane and the Accordion. I have also come across the Pagination control.

My first question: In documentation, the Pagination control is generally described as being a way of navigating through content that is divided into smaller parts. The way I am using it is more akin to simply separating panes of (somewhat unrelated) content onto different pages, as you would with a TabPane. Is there anything wrong with using a Pagination control for this purpose? and are there any pros/cons VS this approach and a TabPane?

I have achieved it with the Pagination control by setting the page factory as follows:

```
this.setPageCount(2);
this.setPageFactory((Integer index) -> {
            if (index == 0) {
                return myFirstPane;
            } else {
                return mySecondPane;
            }
        });
```

where there are two pages, each with its own pane to display. In this case 'this' is representing a class that extends Pagination.

My second question: How much scope is there to customise the Pagination control, e.g. rather than it displaying 1, 2, 3, etc for the pages, can I choose a custom message for each page, e.g. "First pane", "Second pane", etc?

Also, is there a way to position the Pagination control differently, as by default it appears to sit below the panes that I associate with it, but what if I wanted it to appear on top?

Answer (score 0):

The Pagination control is not meant to be customized to suit your specific need, so you might be better off creating your own component. A quick and dirty navigation component that does what you need would look something linke:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // Define the different panes
        StackPane pane1 = new StackPane(new Label("Pane 1"));
        StackPane pane2 = new StackPane(new Label("Pane 2"));

        // This is the control that holds the active pane and the navigation
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        // Create buttons to select active pane
        Button button1 = new Button("Pane 1");
        button1.setOnAction(e -> root.setCenter(pane1));
        button1.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> root.getCenter() == pane1, root.centerProperty()));

        Button button2 = new Button("Pane 2");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> root.setCenter(pane2));
        button2.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> root.getCenter() == pane2, root.centerProperty()));

        // Add navigation to the bottom
        HBox menu = new HBox(button1, button2);
        menu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setBottom(menu);

        // Enable pane1 by default
        root.setCenter(pane1);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Hope this is of help :)

Comment: I forgot to mention - `TabPane` seems to have the exact functionality you want, so don't use a custom component unless you have a reason to, for example to be able to make it look completely different.

Comment: Is there any actual issue though with using the pageFactory of the pagination control as I have - I don't see that I've done anything particularly wrong in writing: this.setPageFactory((Integer index) -> {
            if (index == 0) {
                return myFirstPane;
            } else {
                return mySecondPane;
            }
        });

Comment: No it's fine, but as you've experienced, you can't really change the appearance and text of the pagination control. I've done it a couple of times by using node.lookup and changing the text on different events, but this is error prone and subject to change, since we're mucking with internal API's. There are also several listeners that will override your changes again, so it's an annoying route to take.